# What is the purpose of thisArg in .forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

JavaScript's [forEach documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) states that the `.forEach` syntax is:

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

What is the usage of `thisArg`?

Comment: As the docs say `Optional. Value to use as this when executing callback.` - `if (arguments.length > 1) {T = thisArg;}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking to explain what's already well documented.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix What are you talking about? I ask an example of documentation, which is not clear _for me_

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I've read the documentation and the example that the OP is requiring it's not given.

Comment: A [search for those keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[js]+forEach+thisArg) gives you a lot of examples

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak and the polyfill code sample isn't enough to understand what it does?

Comment: Notice of [meta discussion on this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313790/commentary-deleted-on-question-can-i-know-why)

Answer (score 19):

The `thisArg` can be provided to change the *inner `this`* of the callback function.

Not specifying the `thisArg` results in `this` referencing the `Window` in non strict mode. In strict mode (`"use strict";`) it will be `undefined`.

---

If you were confused by the fact, that `thisArg` ***does nothing*** when using an arrow function:

```
var myObject = { name: 'myObject' };

[1,2].forEach(item => { 
  console.log(item);                     // 1, 2
  console.log(this === myObject, this);  // false  Window {}
}, myObject)
```

It's because:

> ## arrow functions cannot be bound

In an arrow function, the `this` refers to the closest scope's `this` all the way up to Window if no scope provides a `this` value. It works just like a normal variable lookup until some `this` is found.
*To better understand `this` see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ackvf/68f992660a5eda645c4671d3599b2acf#file-understanding-this-js) or [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/EQVwzgpgBGAuBOBLAxrYUD0GqF4NwEjtQICeUyA9gLYUQB2siNA5oQBaJgCwAUAG4CG8KDT7UoAXigByAfACSNAGI1JmbPlIs+TaLDZgoWgCZQyAI0jweEblCjdyNOCdMArcVADeNoSIgAuKTMXSQAabywoAFE+ZBYoADMQGlREMhooRAoABwAbFERYHJJDCHiGCH0C-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-pjJZbYd523Y9r3PZ9v39LSaBg-T8Oo9jxPk9TlYW8zpXrsNdwc-z7hLXN4uSatsuW6rmva+xX23tMMhvSgZuK6d6O24oJZp6NOPXFmDvfFdd0dz3Hut+79fAz3tP1977h+6XleCNcXPfDz7dPT3bgrq-Z-BzuClF-Xcrg1gRDIjRESYBfDcAAZ6JWFtbSl3LmHGes865vSGFoEc4IoSuGyhMNeaDI4x33i4I0h8PAOkkF3HuFAs7cGNrMKUg837Dy4BEZhrCJCsIgXoXM0DYFcG4RGMeJdVyoMru7WeEh55+3gdZAcuDWxMUIavEO98t472vnvBOSdj4gONlfMOm8yEmMrrfCxG8GF93-svQc2tX4uHftQT+p9v6uCNErP+gh4FOMNEYrx4DsCQMKtAGB1A4EOMMEaVYQA).*

---

#### Context binding with normal function.

```
var myObject = { name: 'myObject' };

[1,2].forEach(function(item){ 
  console.log(item);                     // 1, 2
  console.log(this === myObject, this);  // true  {name: "myObject"}
}, myObject)
```

If you don't specify `myObject` at this point, the `this` inside would point to `Window` as with the arrow function.

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble with this.

Answer (score 17):

`thisArg` refers to context which callback should be called, 
basically it is what `this` refers to inside callback. For example:

```
var myObject = { name: 'myObject' };

[1,2].forEach(function(item) { 
 console.log(item); // 1, 2
 console.log(this === myObject); // true
}, myObject)
```

Comment: Note that Arrow functions work [differently and can't be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556558/what-is-the-purpose-of-thisarg-in-foreach/49475566#49475566).

Answer (score 6):

A `this` value is a special object which is related with the `execution context`.

An object in which context the execution context is activated

The value of `this` is determinate only once when entering the context
And it is not possible to assign a new value to this

in your case, providing `thisArg` is like

```
arr.forEach(callback.bind(thisArg));
```

`forEach`, simplified it for you, asking a seperate optional param

Now, if you run this forEach with out `this`

```
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this === window); //true
    console.log(this === arr);    //false
});
```

you get the point!

Comment: Small note: if you don't specify it, `this` will become the global object only in non-strict mode, in strict mode it would be `undefined`. And `this == arr` could be true if `arr` is the global object and it inherits from `Array.prototype` and mode is not strict.

Answer (score 2):

I think these tests will make whole thing clear
just test in your browser console

```
arr=[0];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this === window); //true
    console.log(this === arr);    //false
});

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this === window); //true
    console.log(this === arr);    //false
},this);

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this === window); //false
    console.log(this === arr);    //true
},arr);

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this === window); //false
    console.log(this === arr);    //false
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this often in the context of prototypes and functions:

```js
var MyClass = function() {
  this.GlobalVar = 3;
}

MyClass.prototype.func1 = function(a) {
  return (a == this.GlobalVar);
}

MyClass.prototype.func2 = function(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this.func1(item));
  }, this); // use of thisArg
}

MyClass.prototype.func3 = function(arr) {
  var that = this;
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(that.func1(item));
  }); // also possible without using thisArg
}

MyClass.prototype.func4 = function(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(this.func1(item));
  }); // implementation raising an error, because this.func1 does not exist in that context
}

var arr = [0, 1, 3, 4, 3, 1];
var myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.func2(arr);
/* prints:
false
false
true
false
true
false
*/
myClass.func3(arr) /* same as func2 */
myClass.func4(arr); /* Fails with
Error: {
  "message": "TypeError: this.func1 is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 35,
  "colno": 26
}
*/
```